# Sample Client Side gRPC load balancer

Tags: c#, load-balancing, grpc

I have written a sample gRPC Round Robin Load Balancer which will be attached to the gRPC client. I wanted to know if the following snippet would work for the cases when one of the servers go down. I have checked the following scenarios where it is working fine

- when one of the servers is down from start
- One of the servers go down in the middle of a transaction
- Server Comes back online

My client has the retry option, hence when one of the Server's go down in the middle of a transaction, client retries the same with another Server.

My query here is, is the following implementation correct or is it an incorrect way to achieve gRPC loadbalancing. Any comments on better ways to achieve client side load balancing would be helpful. I tried with HAProxy to do the same but in that case I am not able to create the `Singleton Channel`.

**Note:** I am using the state of the Channel to find out if the Server is up or not.

```
    using Grpc.Core;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Configuration;

    namespace GRPCLoadBalancer

    {   
    static class CustomGRPCLoadBalancerWithSingleton
    {
        private static Queue<Channel> m_WorkingQueue;
        private static readonly int m_waitLimit;
        private static Channel m_currentChosenChannel=null;
        private static object m_reachableQueueLockObject = new object();

        static string serverList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GrpcArticleServerList"];

        static CustomGRPCLoadBalancerWithSingleton()
        {

            m_WorkingQueue = new Queue<Channel>();

            m_waitLimit = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GrpcArticleServerWaitLimitMilliSecond"]); //100           

            string[] allServers = serverList.Split(';');
            for (int i = 0, j = allServers.Length; i < j; i++)
            {
                //singleton objects for all servers            
                var ch = new Channel(allServers[i], ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
                CheckIfConnectionIsWorking(ch);
                m_WorkingQueue.Enqueue(ch);               
            }

        }

        internal static Channel GetWorkingChannel()
        {

            lock (m_reachableQueueLockObject)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < m_WorkingQueue.Count; i++)
                {
                    m_currentChosenChannel = m_WorkingQueue.Dequeue();
                    m_WorkingQueue.Enqueue(m_currentChosenChannel);
                    if (m_currentChosenChannel.State == ChannelState.Idle || m_currentChosenChannel.State == ChannelState.Ready)
                    {                        
                        return m_currentChosenChannel;
                    }


                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        static bool CheckIfConnectionIsWorking(Channel serverChannel)
        {

            if (serverChannel != null)
            {
                try
                {

                    //send the heartbit
                    var client = new EditCMSWindowsService.Messages.EditCMSGrpcService.EditCMSGrpcServiceClient(serverChannel);
                    client.GetContentDetails
                                (new EditCMSWindowsService.Messages.GrpcArticleContentURI()
                                {
                                    BasicId = 1
                                },
                                 null, GetForwardTime(2000));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }


        static DateTime GetForwardTime(int incrementMillisecond)
        {
            return DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(incrementMillisecond).ToUniversalTime();
        }


        public static void DisposeChannels()
        {
            lock (m_reachableQueueLockObject)
            {
                int count = m_WorkingQueue.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < m_WorkingQueue.Count; i++)
                {
                    m_currentChosenChannel = m_WorkingQueue.Dequeue();
                    m_currentChosenChannel.ShutdownAsync();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I updated the above code to not use locking and use an array instead of a Queue and this gave me 3x time faster results. Also Added Connection pooling to create multiple channels for a service if needed. Following is the code:

```
static class CustomGRPCLoadBalancerWithSingleton
{
    static Channel[] _WorkingQueue;
    static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CustomGRPCLoadBalancerWithSingleton));
    static int _poolSize;
    static string serverList = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GrpcArticleServerList"];
    static int _WorkingQueueSize;
    static int _currentIndex =0;

    static CustomGRPCLoadBalancerWithSingleton()
    {

        Int32.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GrpcPoolSize"], out _poolSize);
        if (_poolSize <= 0)
            _poolSize = 1;

        string[] allServers = serverList.Split(new char[] { ';' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (allServers.Length > 0)
        {
            _WorkingQueueSize= allServers.Length * _poolSize;
            _WorkingQueue = new Channel[_WorkingQueueSize];
            int idx = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < _poolSize; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < allServers.Length; i++)
                {
                    //singleton objects for all servers            
                    var ch = new Channel(allServers[i], ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
                    _WorkingQueue[idx] = ch;
                    idx++;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    internal static Channel GetWorkingChannel()
    {
        Channel currentChosenChannel = null;
        int curId = _currentIndex % _WorkingQueueSize;
        int idx = 0;
        while(idx<_WorkingQueueSize)
        {
            currentChosenChannel = _WorkingQueue[curId];
            if (currentChosenChannel.State == ChannelState.Idle || currentChosenChannel.State == ChannelState.Ready)
            {
                //ThreadContext.Properties["ChannelChosen"] = _currentIndex;
                //_log.Error(currentChosenChannel.ResolvedTarget+" " + _currentIndex);
                _currentIndex = ++curId;                    
                return currentChosenChannel;
            }
            curId++;
            curId = curId % _WorkingQueueSize;
            idx++;
        }

        return null;
    }


    public static void DisposeChannels()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _WorkingQueueSize; i++)
        {
            _WorkingQueue[i].ShutdownAsync();
        }
    }
```